# Is anybody using WiX Toolset v5.0.0-rc.1?

Tags: wix

I installed Firegiant Heat Extension, then updated wix to latest version using

```
dotnet tool install --global wix --version 5.0.0-rc.1
```

So I changed a Wix MSI Project from version 4.0.4 to 5.0.0-rc.1

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/5.0.0-rc.1">

</Project>
```

But when I reloaded the project, it fail

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HeatWave support for WiX v5 is coming *very* soon.

Comment: I certainly hope so because rc2 just dropped and GA is probably 2 weeks away and I haven't even been able to look at it yet since HeatWave can't load the projects in VS.